# iOS 7 UINavigationContoller subview autorotate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have an app with navagationController to load several views in portrait. Now I hope to let one of views to be in landscape. So I add some code in the landscape view.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

But it didn't work. It seems that some functions were unavailable in iOS 7. I hope some one to help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code located? Ensure that it is located in the top most pushed or presented view controller. Otherwise it will be ignored.